# Сместить в сторону сохраняя центрирование

Tags: html, css

Есть у меня блок заданой ширины. Нужно внутри выставить по центру другой блок со смещением вправо на `120px`. По центру я выставляю с помощью `margin: 0 auto`. Как можно к такому еще добавить дополнительный отступ справа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
  background: red;
  width: 600px;
}

.inner {
  background: green;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.inner2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 120px;
  background: green;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <br>
  <div class="inner">
    блок по центру
    <br>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="inner2">
    блок по центру
    <br>но со смещением 120px
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
#block1 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  background: grey;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 120px;
}

#block2 {
  margin: auto;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='block1'>
  <div id='block2'> Сдвинутый блок
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- псевдоклассом :before c margin
- вложить внутри еще один блок с `margin-left:120px`
- изнутри `padding-left:120px` (не пойдет, если блок имеет визуальное стили)